# Is the Schroeder Allpass implementation in Freeverb incorrect?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, filter-design, allpass, reverb

I've been looking into the venerable Freeverb and I see that [CCRMA](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/pasp/Freeverb.html) state that it uses 4 Shroeder Allpass filters in series, but when I look at the source code I see:

```
inline float allpass::process(float input)
{
    float output;
    float bufout;
    
    bufout = buffer[bufidx];
    undenormalise(bufout);
    
    output = -input + bufout;
    buffer[bufidx] = input + (bufout*feedback);

    if(++bufidx>=bufsize) bufidx = 0;

    return output;
}
```

To me, this doesn't equate to the standard Shroeder Allpass, but instead something like this:

[image: Freeverb Implementation]

But it should look like this (from CCRMA):

[image: CCRMA Implementation]

Am I overlooking something here, or is CCRMA incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the freeverb "allpass" implementation actually isn't a perfect allpass filter. The implemented filter has a transfer function

$$H(z)=\frac{(1+\alpha)z^{-N}-1}{1-\alpha z^{-N}}\tag{1}$$

The only case for which $(1)$ actually *is* a (scaled) allpass filter occurs if $\alpha$ satisfies

$$\alpha(1+\alpha)=1\tag{2}$$

i.e., $\alpha=(\sqrt{5}-1)/2\approx 0.62$.

The fact that the freeverb filter only approximates an allpass filter is also mentioned [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/pasp/Freeverb_Allpass_Approximation.html).

Comment: Thank you! I've looked at that Freeverb page all morning and didn't see the page with that info. Much appreciated. I think I have to assume that the design was intentional. I wonder what the rationale for this unusual choice was?

Comment: @kippertoffee: You're welcome! As for your last question, I honestly don't have a clue ...

Comment: Manfred Schroeder's original paper on reverb is still a good read: https://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=343 . His original approach used allpass and comb filters and the freeverb implementation seems to by a hybrid of both. (No idea if that's intentional).